# Is there a way to open angular component outside of iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, iframe

I have an aspx application where in an iframe source I am calling URL of angular application. The angular application in turn calls an angular component which opens up as pop-up on click of button. But the pop-up is opening inside the iframe. The requirement is that pop-up should open outside of iframe. Can some one suggest something here?

Comment: The angular app could send a [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to the parent, and the parent could open the popup.

Comment: is there a working example you have for postMessage from Angular to ASPX application?